# Storage trigger in Cloud Functions loops forever

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I have this function that retrieves an uploaded image from google storage bucket and then generates a thumbnail of the image. The function works well but it will not stop running. 
This is the function

```
 const thumbarray = []
 exports.generateTHUMBPIC = 
functions.storage.object('productpics/{pushId}').onFinalize((object, context) => {

// [START eventAttributes]
const fileBucket = object.bucket; // The Storage bucket that contains the file.
const filePath = object.name; // File path in the bucket.
const contentType = object.contentType; // File content type.
const resourceState = object.resourceState; // The resourceState is 'exists' or 'not_exists' (for file/folder deletions).
const metageneration = object.metageneration; // Number of times metadata has been generated. New objects have a value of 1.

const fileDir1 = path.dirname(filePath);
const fileName0 = path.basename(filePath);

const fileDir = fileDir1.replace('productpics/', '')

console.log("file directory ***********",fileDir)

console.log("This is the object ",object)
 console.log("This is the object ",context)

var listingid = fileDir.split("*")[1];
var userid = fileDir.split("*")[0];
var productid = fileDir.split("*")[2];
var thumbname = fileDir.split("*")[3]; // thumbnail 1 or 2 or 3
thumbarray.push(thumbname);
console.log("product id  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^",productid)

console.log("This is the file path ",filePath)
console.log('This is the created path',"productpics/ "+ context.params.pushId +" /productimg" );



const thumbFilePath = path.normalize(path.join(fileDir1, `${THUMB_PREFIX}${productid}`));
const tempLocalFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filePath);
const tempLocalDir = path.dirname(tempLocalFile);
const tempLocalThumbFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), thumbFilePath);
const thumbnail_bucket = "thumbnails/"+fileDir;


    console.log('This is the thumb nail bucket ', thumbnail_bucket);

// [END eventAttributes]

// [START stopConditions]
// Exit if this is triggered on a file that is not an image.
if (!contentType.startsWith('image/')) {
    console.log('This is not an image.');
    return null;
}


// Exit if the image is already a thumbnail.
if (productid.startsWith(THUMB_PREFIX)) {
    console.log('Already a Thumbnail.');
    return null;
}

// Download file from bucket.
const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket);
const file = bucket.file(filePath);
const thumbFile = bucket.file(thumbFilePath);

const metadata = {
    contentType: contentType,
};
// Create the temp directory where the storage file will be downloaded.
return mkdirp(tempLocalDir).then(() => {

    console.log("This is the tempLocalfile ", tempLocalFile)
    // Download file from bucket.
    return file.download({
        destination: tempLocalFile
    });
}).then(() => {
     // Generate a thumbnail using ImageMagick.
    return spawn('convert', [tempLocalFile, '-thumbnail', `${THUMB_MAX_WIDTH}x${THUMB_MAX_HEIGHT}>`, tempLocalThumbFile], {
        capture: ['stdout', 'stderr']
    });
}).then(() => {
    console.log('Thumbnail created at', tempLocalThumbFile);
    // Uploading the Thumbnail.
               console.log("thumb file use to be saved in ",thumbFilePath)

    return bucket.upload(tempLocalThumbFile, {
        destination: thumbnail_bucket,
        metadata: metadata
    });
})
   .then(() => {
    console.log('Thumbnail uploaded to Storage at', thumbnail_bucket);
    // Once the image has been uploaded delete the local files to free up disk space.
    fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalFile);
    // fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalThumbFile);
    // Get the Signed URLs for the thumbnail and original image.
    const config = {
        action: 'read',
        expires: '03-01-2500',
    };
    return Promise.all([
        thumbFile.getSignedUrl(config),
        file.getSignedUrl(config),
    ]);
}).then((results) => {
    // console.log('Got Signed URLs.');
    // var thumbname = fileName0.split("*")[2];

    const thumbResult = results[0];
    const originalResult = results[1];
    const thumbFileUrl = thumbResult[0];
    const fileUrl = originalResult[0];

    var updates = {};


    updates['Listings/' + listingid + "/" + thumbname + "thumb"] = thumbFileUrl;
    // updates['Listings/' + fileName +'/'+ thumbname] = thumbFileUrl;

    return admin.database().ref().update(updates);


}).then(() => console.log('Thumbnail URLs saved to database.'));
})
```

I could not figure out what I am doing wrongly. It seems like it is triggering itself. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you upload a file to Cloud Storage during a Cloud Storage trigger, your function will get once for each upload.

If you want to prevent this, you will need a way to terminate the function early by checking to see if the changed file is one that you want to process, and returning out of the function without any more processing.

For example, take a look at [some of the official samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/Node-8/convert-images/functions/index.js#L47).